# How do I determine which are the foreground .NET threads from WinDBG?

Tags: windbg

How do I determine which are the foreground .NET threads from WinDBG ?
Using the !threads command the SOS extenstion tells us the count of the foreground threads but not which ones.

Answer (score 6):

The state flag in the `!threads` output holds a lot of information. If the `0x00000200` flag is set the thread is a background thread.

In SOS for .NET 4 and PSSCOR2, there's a `!threadstate` command, that will list the texts for a given flag value. If you don't have that, there's an overview of the flags in the rotor source code and in Debugging .NET 2.0 applications by John Robbins.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It will be nice to see all the thread state flags from the SOS extension.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the thread state values given in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee817657%28pandp.10%29.aspx) and find out if a thread is a background thread or not.

> TS_Background 0x00000200  Thread is a
>   background thread

Answer (score 0):

[Netext](https://netext.codeplex.com/)'s command `!wthreads` shows type and status information:

```
0:011> !wthreads
   Id OSId Address  Domain   Alloc Start:End   COM  GC Type  Locks Type / Status             Last Exception
    1 1854 0074f580 00748cd0 02c19308:02c1b2e8 STA  Preemptive   0                          
    2 1890 0075ab18 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Background|Finalizer     
    3 1bac 080ecb98 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Background|Worker        
    4 ---- 08106068 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Worker|Terminated        
    5 ---- 0810e988 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Worker|Terminated        
    6 ---- 080eb1d0 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Worker|Terminated        
    7 081c 080fcb48 00748cd0 00000000:00000000 MTA  Preemptive   0 Background|IOCPort
```